# sed returns "sed: command garbled"

Tags: linux, bash, sed, replace

I have this data in file.txt:

```
1234-abca-dgdsf-kds-2;abc dfsfds 2
123-abcdegfs-sdsd;dsfdsf dfd f
12523-cvjbsvndv-dvd-dvdv;dsfdsfpage
```

I want to replace the string after "-" and up to ";" with just ";", so that I get:

```
1234;abc dfsfds 2 
123;dsfdsf dfd f 
12523;dsfdsfpage
```

I tried with the command:

```
sed -e "s/-.*;/;" file.txt
```

But it gives me the following error:

> sed command garbled

Why is this happening?

Comment: I get a much more expressive error message in 2017: `sed: -e expression #1, char 8: unterminated `s' command`

Comment: @AnthonySottile probably this was run in Solaris. I arrived here from [Sed command garbled on Solaris](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45982603/1983854)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work :

```
sed 's/-.*;/;/g' file > newFile
```

Answer (score 2):

`sed` replacement commands are defined as ([source](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.txt)):

> ```
> 's/REGEXP/REPLACEMENT/[FLAGS]'
> ```
>
> (substitute) Match the regular-expression against the content of the pattern space.  If found, replace matched string with REPLACEMENT.

However, you are saying:

```
sed "s/-.*;/;"
```

That is:

```
sed "s/REGEXP/REPLACEMENT"
```

And hence missing a "/" at the end of the expression. Just add it to have:

```
sed "s/-.*;/;/"
#            ^
```

Comment: Excellent answer as you explain the problem!

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a slash at the end of the `sed` command:

Should be `"s/-.*;/;/"`

Answer (score 1):

`-.*` here the `*` greedy, so this would fail if there are more than one `;`

```
echo "12523-cvjbsvndv-dvd-dvdv;dsfdsfpage;test" | sed -e "s/-.*;/;/"
12523;test
```

Change to `-[^;]*`

```
echo "12523-cvjbsvndv-dvd-dvdv;dsfdsfpage;test" | sed -e "s/-[^;]*;/;/"
12523;dsfdsfpage;test
```