# sed command garbled for bash 3.0

Tags: bash, sed

I have gone through other threads [Sed command garbled didnt work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19388443/sed-command-garbled-didnt-work)
but it didn't helped me

```
flag=1
echo "enter the folder into which you want to capture"
read logs
mkdir $logs
path=/user/gur40139/shell/angel
 for i in $path/*.tra*
  do
   value=$( grep -ic \*= $i )
     if [ $value -ge $flag ]
      then
         name=`basename $i .tra\*`
         echo -e "count is $value\n" >> $path/$logs/log_"$name".txt
         sed -n '/\*=/ {n;p}' $i|sed 2n\;G >> $path/$logs/log_"$name".txt
     fi
  done
 echo -e "\nDone\n"
```

**Error:**

sed: command garbled: /\*=/ {n;p}

Additional Note: This code is working properly on bash 4.1 version but I want to test it in 3.0, There many options which are not even working like sed --version.

Comment: What OS and sed version?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
sed -n '/\*=/ {n;p;}' ...
```

you need to terminate the line after the `p` so a `;` or a new line. Your code will certainly work on recent GNU sed but not on posix  version

Comment: My code is working properly in gnu bash 4.1 but not in bash 3.0

Comment: seems it is not a sed problem but an environment problem. is it on the same machine or on different machine (i suppose). your sed command is basic so even old sed version should accept it. What give a `set -vx ` befor your sed line ?