# Sed command garbled on Solaris

Tags: unix, sed, solaris

I'm new to `sed` and trying to replace a string on Solaris. I have a simple text file `test.txt` containing values:

```
apple
grape
orange
```

Now I'm trying this basic sed command to replace 'apple' with 'banana':

```
sed -e 's/apple/banana' test.txt > test.tmp && mv "$TMP" test.txt
```

Returns error: *sed: command garbled: s/apple/banana* on Solaris 10.

What is wrong with this simple code? Thanks

Comment: Compare endings of the sed expressions: `sed -e 's/apple/banana/g' test.txt`

Comment: You need a `/` after "banana".

Comment: When you do not want to move a tmp file, you can try `printf "%s\n" %s/apple/banana/ w q | ed -s test.txt`.